# Get the value of each dynamic text box per number

Tags: javascript, php, multidimensional-array

I'm developing an Online Examination System. My problem is I need to get the value of each options (appended) per question number.

**EXAMPLE:**

**Question # 1:**

- a. dog
- b. cat
- c. tiger

**Question # 2:**

- a. blue
- b. red

Must get the option values of:

**Question # 1:** which is dog, cat, tiger

and

**Question # 2:** which is blue,red

then

Insert to table (one question per row in the database table)

---

This is my array:

The highlighted part is the number of html elements which is the options per question

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uePtj.png)

I want output like the highlighted per question:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Timt.png)

This is my code:

```
// COUNT THE NUMBER OF QUESTIONS
$numFields = count($_POST['fields']['questions']);

// NUMBER OF OPTIONS PER QUESTION NUMBER PUT ALL TO ARRAY
$arrNumOpt = $_POST['arrNumOpt'];
$arrNumOpt = explode(",",$arrNumOpt);   


// OPTIONS OF ALL QUESTION PER NUMBER PUT ALL TO ARRAY
$arrOption = array(); 
$arrOption = $_POST['fields']['options']; 

for ($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++) 
{

    $count = $arrNumOpt[$i]; 

    $splitOpt = array_chunk($arrOption,$count); 

    var_dump($splitOpt[$i]);
}
```

Comment: tried to count all the number of appended options per question number then array_chunk using a loop but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

if the questions are multiple choice using select you can use 
$_POST['fields']['questions'][] to capture those into multi dimensional array in POST.

If you don't have an access to the HTML, you can do a nested loop:

```
$main_count = 0;
foreach($_POST['options_per_question'] as $question_no => $count){
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $return_array[$question_no][$i] = $_POST['options'][$main_count++];
    }
}
```

I can only give hints, as your variables are bit vague and I am not sure how the POST looks like

Comment: Can u give a  example? Thank you

Comment: if you have access to the html form, you can add the fields such as: name="field[question1][]" etc, this will format the array after the form is submitted

Comment: I have this textarea for options <textarea name="fields[options][]"></textarea> 





In the $_POST['options_per_question'] is the number of options per question? or the values all together using array?

Comment: yes, it's options_per_question would be an array that you go through using foreach loop. I edited the question as I reused a variable name

Comment: didn't work bro. check my question here it's more specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499543/get-the-value-of-each-dynamic-text-box-and-put-into-array-per-number/35499820#35499820